# How can I make a touch screen button press?

Tags: css, user-interface, button, touch, touchscreen

Mediaashley has a 3D css button using :before and :after that looks cool with a mouse click, but I need a touch screen button that has the same effect, and this one doesn't seem to work that way. The screen press doesn't give a button press animation like the mouse click does. Is there a simple tweak that will make it do that? Thanks!

HTML

```
<p>Click to activate.</p>
<p>&nbsp</p>
<p>
<button class="facebook"></button>
<button class="twitter"></button>
<button class="in"></button>
<button class="vimeo"></button>
</p>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'socialfont';
    src: url('http://mediaashley.com/MyFont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 70px;
}

button {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:Arial, "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #07526e;
  padding-top:6px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  left:30px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  border: none;
  background: #109bce;
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(14,137,182) 0%, rgb(22,179,236) 100%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #07526e, 0px 10px 5px #999;
}

button:active {
  top:3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 2px 0px 0px #07526e, 0px 5px 3px #999;
}

button:before {
  font-family: 'socialfont';
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  content:"\F020";
  width:85px;
  height:90px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  padding-top:10px;
  top:10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #07526e;

}

button:active:before {
  top: 7px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #07526e, 0px 5px 1px #07526e/*, 3px 0px 1px #07526e, 3px 3px 1px #07526e,
     -2px 0px 1px #68cff2*/;
}

.twitter:before {
  content:"\F021";
}
.in:before {
  content:"\F022";
}
.vimeo:before{
  content:"\F024";

}
```

http://codepen.io/mediaashley/pen/kLbGf

Comment: Use `:focus` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
Put your buttons into a `<div></div>` like this: `<div ontouchstart=""></div>`

**Method 2:**
Try `<button ontouchstart=""></button>`

**Method 3:**
You can try to change the CSS class of your button with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById(id).ontouchstart = function (event) {
    ...
}
```

Hope I could help you.